# Hadoop Namenode startup failure due to InconsistentFSSStateException

Tags: azure, hadoop, cluster-computing, startup

I am setting up a Hadoop (v1.1.1) cluster on Windows Azure. I am trying to launch the namenode process by using:

`service hadoop-namenode start`

However I am consistently getting the following error which is associated with when the VM reboots being wiped. I moved this directory out so it would not be deleted each time but it still occurs. Any help would be gratefully received.

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = master/10.77.42.61
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.1 -r 1411108; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Mon Nov 19 10:44:13 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2012-12-13 09:38:54,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2012-12-13 09:38:54,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2012-12-13 09:38:54,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 60 second(s).
2012-12-13 09:38:54,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2012-12-13 09:38:54,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2012-12-13 09:38:54,714 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2012-12-13 09:38:54,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2012-12-13 09:38:54,804 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2012-12-13 09:38:54,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 2.475 MB
2012-12-13 09:38:54,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
2012-12-13 09:38:54,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=262144, actual=262144
2012-12-13 09:38:54,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hdfs
2012-12-13 09:38:54,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2012-12-13 09:38:54,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2012-12-13 09:38:54,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2012-12-13 09:38:54,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2012-12-13 09:38:55,429 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2012-12-13 09:38:55,465 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2012-12-13 09:38:55,471 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot access storage directory /hadoop/name
2012-12-13 09:38:55,474 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1412)
2012-12-13 09:38:55,476 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /hadoop/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the process over the directory?

Answer (score 2):

Change the permissions of the directory, which you have specified as the value of the "dfs.name.dir" property in your hdfs-site.xml file, to 755 and also change the user of this directory to the current user.BTW, Were you able to do a successful format?

Comment: I was able to so a successful format. I performed chmod 755 on the name folder and upon running service hadoop-namenode start I get the following: ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hadoop/name/current/VERSION (Permission denied) Any other ideas?

Comment: that's the root cause. it is not advisable to format hdfs from the root user. try "sudo service hadoop-namenode start"